# How do I install a fan when the electrical box has 2 white and 2 black and 2 ground wires?

Tags: electrical

I am trying to install a ceiling fan with remote and the problem I am having is that there are 2 black, 2 white and 2 copper(ground) wires.

The first thing I did was to connect the red wire from the fan to the black wire from the box. Then connected the white wire from the fan to the white wire from the box. Next, I connected one of the ground wires to the screw in the box and connected the other ground with the ground wire from the fan and the fan bracket. Lastly, I connected the white wire from the the receiver (for the remote) to the white wire of the fan, the black wire from the receiver to the black wire of the fan, and the blue wire from the receiver to the blue wire of the fan. I put caps over the extra white and black wires.

After this I tried turning the fan on via the remote and the pull-chains, but it did not work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: We need to understand how the two black and two white wires were connected before you attempted to install the fan.

Answer (score -1):

Usually only the receiver is attached to the mains. One set of receiver wires (usually black/white/bare or green) go to the circuit and another set of receiver wires, often with two hots (black, red or blue) go to fan and light separately, and then white to white and ground to ground.

If there is a receiver, the fans own wires should generally NOT be attached to the mains.

Comment: Happy to withdraw if this is wrong, but clarification on the problem would be appreciated.